# Is Swift 3 fully backwards compatible with previous OS versions

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, macos-sierra

I recently began developing a Mac app in Swift 3.0 using the Xcode 8 beta. I plan to finish development by the middle of August which would be before the public release of macOS. My current development machine runs El Capitan and my compiled Swift 3.0 code runs well on the current operating system version, which is a good sign, but I'm slightly concerned that there may be some issues running the code on previous OS X versions (e.g. 10.10). Is this a valid concern? In addition, will I even be able to release the app with Swift 3.0 before macOS is released?

Comment: *Swift* apps are compatible down to 10.9 (Mavericks). But the real difficulty is to make the app look and behave consistently across all versions (some SDKs change, some are added).

Comment: Eric D, It seems as though Swift 3.0's major differences are API syntax changes (e.g. Grand Central Dispatch had a major syntax swiftizing and restructuring, but I doubt much of the actual implementation was modified, if any). If this is the case, then behavioral changes shouldn't be a huge concern, correct?

Comment: Correct - and important changes first go through usual deprecation steps anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Swift app is shipped with the Swift standard library included. The advantage of this is that it can run on multiple OS versions by default. The negative point is that it adds a few MB to your final app bundle.

So yes, your app will work on previous versions but keep in mind that you can't submit apps to the Mac App Store until Xcode 8 GM will be released.

Comment: So any code written in Swift 3 cannot be released until macOS is released?

Comment: @Jonny: Read last paragraph... https://developer.apple.com/support/beta-software/

Comment: @l'L'l, Thanks for the link. So am I correct in assuming that all implementation code within the Swift standard library is included in the application bundle?

Comment: However, you cannot build an app with Swift for iOS 6 and earlier, also the same applies to OS X .